# Flutter --> Listile and Streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
 const Messages ({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("messages").snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Errror ${snapshot.error}");
    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents
          .map<Widget>((doc) => ListTile(
                title: Text(doc['name']),
                subtitle: Text(doc['message']),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

Hello everyone, we can pull data from firebase. We can print to Debugprint. But when we try to print on the screen using the list, we get an error. Can you help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you need to wrap the `ListTile` widget with a `Material` Widget:

```
children: snapshot.data.documents
          .map<Widget>((doc) => Card(child: ListTile(
                title: Text(doc['name']),
                subtitle: Text(doc['message']),
              )))
          .toList(),
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't. That error has gone, but the values I am pulling from the firebase are now coming to null.

Comment: remove the space here `Firestore.instance.collection("messages").snapshots()` from `messages` in your code

Comment: it happened thnx so much !

Answer (score 0):

if you read what the error is telling you you might find the answer to this.
in flutter material, normally widgets must be placed on top of some other widgets. just like we put tiles after we concreted the floor. so the concrete provides a base for the tiles.

what you are missing is that the listview is not on top of a base material widget. to fix that simply wrap them in a Scaffold or any similar base widgets. if you are using scaffold use it as the root widget.

like this,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body : //Your widget
    )
```